# Building corefx\src\System.Collections\System.Collections.sln solution fails

Tags: c#, .net-core

After a clean sync of [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) I get the following error while trying to build corefx\src\System.Collections\System.Collections.sln using VS 2015. I'd assume this should work from a clean sync. Am I the only one or are others seeing this as well? If I resolve the failure I'll post what I find so it'll show up on searches.

```
Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
Failed to resolve all project references for 'System.Collections'. The package restore result for 'System.Collections' may be incomplete.
Failed to resolve all project references for 'System.Collections.Tests'. The package restore result for 'System.Collections.Tests' may be incomplete.
Failed to resolve all project references for 'System.Collections'. The package restore result for 'System.Collections.Tests' may be incomplete.
xunit.abstractions 2.0.0 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
Some packages are not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
NuGet package restore failed.
1>------ Build started: Project: System.Collections, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\kingc\Documents\Git\corefx\packages\Microsoft.DotNet.BuildTools.1.0.25-prerelease-00121\lib\sign.targets(39,5): error : C:\Users\kingc\Documents\Git\corefx\bin/obj/Windows_NT.AnyCPU.Debug\System.Collections\System.Collections.dll: PE file is already strong-name signed.
2>------ Build started: Project: System.Collections.Tests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  System.Collections.Tests -> C:\Users\kingc\Documents\Git\corefx\bin\Windows_NT.AnyCPU.Debug\System.Collections.Tests\System.Collections.Tests.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution files do not reference all dependent projects. Simply adding the projects referenced by the solution projects will fix warnings about not being able to resolve all project references for XXX.

The testing harness [is not yet compatible](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/building/windows-instructions.md) with coreclr which is why this is generated:

```
xunit.abstractions 2.0.0 is not compatible with DNXCore,Version=v5.0.
```